# AES-CBC incorrect usage

Tags: encryption, openssl

I am trying to do AES-CBC cipher and decipher via openssl, however, I am not able to get the correct output. Please advise me. Thank you.

### cipher

clr;
MSG_CIPHERED_HEX="920e5af8b78702c778a919f7969a1f8cba578f11693673035213daf02500c50a"
IV="00000000000000000000000000000000" 
KEY="00000000000000000000000000000000"
echo -n "$MSG_CIPHERED_HEX" | xxd -r -p | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -K $KEY -iv $IV | xxd -p | tr -d '\n'

### decipher

clr;
MSG_CIPHERED_HEX="734563526574204d6553734167452030300a0e0e0e0e0e0e0e0e0e0e0e0e0e0e"
echo $MSG_CIPHERED_HEX 
MSG_ASCII=`echo $MSG_HEX | xxd -p -r | tr -d '\n'`; echo $MSG_ASCII > tmp.ciphered.file.ascii;
openssl enc -d -aes-128-cbc -K $KEY -iv $IV -in tmp.ciphered.file.ascii -out out.txt
cat out.txt | xxd -p # | tr -d '\n' 
rm -rf tmp.ciphered.file.ascii  out.txt

There seemed to be data formatting issue:
$ #decipher
MSG_CIPHERED_HEX="920e5af8b78702c778a919f7969a1f8cba578f11693673035213daf02500c50a" IV="00000000000000000000000000000000" KEY="00000000000000000000000000000000" echo -n "$MSG_CIPHERED_HEX" | xxd -r -p | openssl enc -d -aes-128-cbc -K $KEY -iv $IV | xxd -p | tr -d '\n'

Ans:
734563526574204d6553734167452030300a (truncated)

$ #cipher
MSG_CIPHERED_HEX="920e5af8b78702c778a919f7969a1f8cba578f11693673035213daf02500c50a" IV="00000000000000000000000000000000" KEY="00000000000000000000000000000000" echo -n "$MSG_CIPHERED_HEX" | xxd -r -p | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -K $KEY -iv $IV | xxd -p | tr -d '\n'

Ans:
236999001256bd4131dffa3417c29bfc597a43f6bde387ba0e42da86e67cfff42890e4f6e84c0e70753a9db754df996e

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

The `e0e0e0e0e0e0e0e0e0e0e0e0e0e` is 14 bytes of padding. If you specify padding  on decryption it will be automatically removed.

See [PKCS7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7).